# extending class SharedArrayBuffer results in "Constructor SharedArrayBuffer required 'new'"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to extend the `SharedArrayBuffer` class to easily pass around Component data for use within worker threads as we're processing tens of thousands of entities per second. This is my code at the moment.

```
export default abstract class Component extends SharedArrayBuffer {
  public name: String; 
  public data: DataView;

  public constructor(size) {
      super(size); 
      this.data = new DataView(this); 
      this.name = this.constructor.name.toLowerCase(); 
  }
}
```

I then have a component that extends the abstract class component called `Position`.

```
export default class Position extends Component {
    public constructor(x: number = 0, y: number = 0, layer: number = 0) {
        super(12); 
        this.data.setUint32(0, x);
        this.data.setUint32(4, y);
        this.data.setUint32(8, layer);
    }

    get x() { return this.data.getUint32(0); }
    set x(value: number) { this.data.setUint32(0, value); }

    get y() { return this.data.getUint32(4); }
    set y(value: number) { this.data.setUint32(4, value); }

    get layer() { return this.data.getUint32(8); }
    set layer(value: number) { this.data.setUint32(8, value); }
}
```

When creating a Position component through `new Position(...)` I receive the following error:

> Component.js:19
> var _this = _super.call(this, size) || this;
> ^
>
> TypeError: Constructor SharedArrayBuffer requires 'new'

Below you can find the JavaScript that is created from the TypeScript code.

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(b, p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Component = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Component, _super);
    function Component(size) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, size) || this;
        _this.data = new DataView(_this);
        _this.name = _this.constructor.name.toLowerCase();
        return _this;
    }
    return Component;
}(SharedArrayBuffer));
exports.default = Component;
```

What is the best way to ensure that the constructor of SharedArrayBuffer is called when `super` is executed to prevent this error?

Comment: You need to transpile to ES6 `class` syntax. ES5 cannot subclass builtins.

Comment: That said, I see no reason to use subclassing here. Composition will suit you better than inheritance. You're already doing it for the `DataView` anyway. Just drop the `extends SharedArrayBuffer` and `super(size)`, and do `this.data = new DataView(new SharedArrayBuffer(size))` instead